# response string shows,Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle."Cycle Detected" response (400)

Tags: json, swift3, xcode8, ios10

### JSON

```
[
{ 
      "userName”:”abcd”,
      "phoneNumber”:”987456321”,
      "latitude":12.911757,
      "longitude":80.2162277,
      "speed":0,
      "updatedOn":"Dec 20, 2016 2:12:56 AM",
      "userMessage":"Hello"
   },
   { 
      "userName”:”EFGH”,
      "phoneNumber”:”987546123”,
      "latitude":12.911757,
      "longitude":80.2162277,
      "speed":0,
      "updatedOn":"Dec 20, 2016 7:58:49 AM",
      "userMessage":"Hello"
   }
]
```

**CODE**:

```
let responseString:String = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
            print(responseString)


let myJSON  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
                    for  dictionary in myJSON
                    {
                       if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "phoneNumber") as! String) != (dictionary["phoneNumber"] as! String)
                       {
                        let uname = dictionary["userName"] as! String
                        let phoneNo = dictionary["phoneNumber"] as! String
                        let lat = dictionary["latitude"] as! Double
                        let long = dictionary["longitude"] as! Double
                        let speed = dictionary["speed"] as! Int
                        //let time = dictionary["updatedOn"] as! String
                        let userMessage = dictionary["userMessage"] as! String

                        self.array_usermsg.append(userMessage)
                        let marker = GMSMarker()
                        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "car.jpg")
                        marker.map = self.mapViewFist
                        }
                    }
```

response string shows: "Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle". "Cycle Detected" response (400).

Comment: That's a nice a error message, JSON block, and code block you have there. Do you have a question to go with them too? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check it on http://jsonlint.com. – Hint: have a close look at the quotation marks.

Comment: Is that really the JSON? Or did you edit it? The reason I ask is that I notice that some of your quotation marks are "smart" quotations (open or closing quotation marks). I'm trying to understand if your JSON was corrupted somehow, or whether that happened as you were editing your question...

Comment: Also, do you know that this is what your JSON looked like? Or is this what you _think_ it should look like. Again, is this JSON the real contents (i.e. did you `let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` and then print that `responseString`)?

Comment: Thats valid JSON format. I am sure. Rob I checked response string,Cycle Detected Description: Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle."Cycle Detected" response (400) -->\n</BODY>\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \0"

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. I took the following steps which solved the issue (after I freaked out for a while):

1. Calm down.
2. Go to **Windows Settings** > **Network & Internet** > **Proxy**
3. If you have a **Manual Proxy Setup**, leave it on but also turn on the slider for **Automatically detect settings**.
4. Under **Manual Proxy Setup** header, check the option: **Don't use the proxy server for local (intranet) addresses.**

This should fix the issue. It did for me, at least.

Comment: Gone through this today but my proxy was set directly in postman.